¿porque no puedo validar campo con apostrofes en laravel 10?
Hola me e encontrado con un problema extraño, y es que no soy capaz de validar campos que tengan apostrofes. Como por ejemplo God's
Probé todas estas opciones:
'title' => 'required|string'
'title' => ['required', 'string','regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\'\!]+$/'],
"required|string|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\'\!]+$/"

La versión de laravel es 10, en realidad probé con mas opciones pero con ninguna e sido capaz de que se permita el ingreso de apostrofes.

Intenta así:
'title' => ['required', 'string', "regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-\'\!]+$/"]

